# Remove empty object from JSON

Tags: json, jolt

Source JSON:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "status": "active",
  "media": [
    {
      "content": {
        "logo": {
          "id": 24808
        }
      },
      "web": {
        "primary": {
          "id": 909
        }
      },
      "description": {},
      "status": "blocked"
    }
  ]
}
```

Field `description` can be empty `{}`, but sometimes not. How can I remove object `description` only if it's an empty? Or for example `web` can be empty too. So main goal - remove empty objects from `media` array.

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "status": "active",
  "media": [
    {
      "content": {
        "logo": {
          "id": 24808
        }
      },
      "web": {
        "primary": {
          "id": 909
        }
      },
      "status": "blocked"
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Today I noticed some problem. When inside `content`, `web` or `description` multiple objects like in this example:

```json
{
   "id":3,
   "status":"active",
   "media":[
      {
         "content":{
            "logo":{
               "id":24808
            },
            "main_theme":{
               "id":91390
            },
            "preview_pic":{
               "id":11
            }
         },
         "web":{
            "primary":{
               "id":909
            },
            "outer_link":{
               "id":501
            }
         },
         "description":{
            
         },
         "status":"blocked"
      }
   ]
}
```

Script creates duplicates:
[image: dups]

Comment: This is not helpful @BrahmaDev. The user is using the jolt library, which is written in Java not JavaScript.

Comment: No problem @BrahmaDev . But be sure to read which language it is is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "media": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "@1": "&4[&3].&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

this way, we're trying to go deeper in order to get rid of the respective counterpart value which will be a `null` for the `"description"` attribute in this case.

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

**Edit** : the following one will be a more generic alternative considering the case you have encountered lately :

```json
[
  { // eliminate the attributes with {} on the RHS 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "media": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3[&2].&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "media": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": ["=notNull", "NulL"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // keep the non-nested attributes similar to "status"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "media": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "NulL": {
                "$1": "&5[&4].&3"
              },
              "*": "&4[&3].&2.&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Today I noticed some problem. When inside `content`,` web` or `description` multiple objects, script duplicates these objects multiple times (number of dups = number of objects)

Comment: Well, I've just edited @fujidaon , take care.

Comment: Thanks! Very hard to understand :D, but works as expected!